# How do I use javascript and document.querySelector to extract text from the latest post in a Discord channel?

Tags: javascript, html, text, extract

Using javascript and "document.querySelector" to successfully identify and extract text from the last message on a Discord channel is proving difficult. I've done this successfully on other websites by using :last-child, as such:

```
document.querySelector(“container:last-child”).innerContent
```

However, this doesn't seem to work on Discord channels. Their data is structured as nested .div element(instead of lists, which I've had success with in the past). Here's an example of the Discord structure:

```
<div class="scrollerInner-2YIMLh" aria-label="Messages in -rules-you-must-read" role="log" aria-orientation="vertical" data-list-id="chat-messages" tabindex="0" aria-live="off"><span class="navigationDescription-3hiGKr" id="messagesNavigationDescription" aria-hidden="true">Use the up and down arrow keys to navigate between messages quickly. New messages will be added to the bottom of the list as they come in.</span>
    <div class="container-3RCQyg" id="chat-messages-701975798466216026">
        <div class="container-3zqIcM">
            <div class="inner-3GZ54g">
                <div>
                    <div class="colorHeaderPrimary-26Jzh- size32-o_H79z titleName-3-Lp3Z">
                        <p>Welcome to</p>
                        <p>Nookazon</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="colorHeaderSecondary-3Sp3Ft size14-e6ZScH subtitle-2UIIw0 noChildren-1pQQQE">This is the beginning of this server. </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-718562073835208774" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-718562073835208774">
        <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><span class="latin24CompactTimeStamp-2V7XIQ timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampVisibleOnHover-2bQeI4 alt-1uNpEt"><span aria-label="1:29 PM"><i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">[</i>1:29 PM<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">] </i></span></span>
            <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC"><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":eight:" src="/assets/71de2e3efd19455f1c63b9bd00329ec5.svg" alt=":eight:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>Spam</strong>
                <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
                    <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
                    <blockquote>Use of our website or Discord server in any way deemed to be spam will result in the termination of your account. This includes but is not limited to excessively using all capitalizations or spaces, and posting repeatedly, low effort, and/or inappropriate messages that contribute little to no meaning in the discussion regardless of timeframe, chain mail, or messages that are overall irrelevant. Excessively large messages, 15 lines or greater, are also considered spam, and will be dealt with accordingly. Please refrain from spamming pings, images, messages, or listings. Attempting to contact other users in any way for purposes deemed to be spam will not be tolerated. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":speech_balloon:" src="/assets/df8b5c1e4abb97e748071aeb28f1ba38.svg" alt=":speech_balloon:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>Use Chat and Trade Channels Appropriately</strong> Please use the appropriate trade channels for your discussions. All channel descriptions are located at the top of each channel. If you are unsure about where to post, please ask in <span class="wrapper-3WhCwL mention interactive" tabindex="0" role="button">#❔-help</span>. Punishments for trolling/baiting are more severe in the trading channels. You may receive a mute for any off-topic content in these channels. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":vibration_mode:" src="/assets/c039d0f4fb5cee040c7aa7c80da104d8.svg" alt=":vibration_mode:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>No Mass Pings</strong> Mass pinging individuals will result in an <em>auto-ban</em>. You may ping up to <strong><u>three</u></strong> mods or @ emergency if attention is needed in a channel. Abuse may result in a bite/ban. </blockquote>
                </div><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":clipboard:" src="/assets/1bfac5a4300cf5668073bd17d178e89e.svg" alt=":clipboard:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>Keep your trading lists concise</strong>.
                <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
                    <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
                    <blockquote>If you have more than 10 items to trade per item category, please add them to your catalog on the site and share your Nookazon profile link in the appropriate trade channel. </blockquote>
                </div><em> </em>
                <time datetime="2021-01-04T04:35:25.481Z" class="edited-3sfAzf" role="note" aria-label="Sunday, January 3, 2021 8:35 PM">(edited)</time>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-1ov-mD"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-718562140486631455" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-718562140486631455">
        <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><span class="latin24CompactTimeStamp-2V7XIQ timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampVisibleOnHover-2bQeI4 alt-1uNpEt"><span aria-label="1:29 PM"><i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">[</i>1:29 PM<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">] </i></span></span>
            <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC"><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":keycap_ten:" src="/assets/5e1630b749695f21d61dcf55fc09c2b6.svg" alt=":keycap_ten:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":bangbang:" src="/assets/9a13b8821ec2c880981df4bf3ce07177.svg" alt=":bangbang:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span><strong><u>Tarantula Bites</u></strong><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":bangbang:" src="/assets/9a13b8821ec2c880981df4bf3ce07177.svg" alt=":bangbang:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>
                <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
                    <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
                    <blockquote> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_blue_diamond:" src="/assets/85e5fb9f60873c46d98c8ab4efdf4066.svg" alt=":small_blue_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Ignorance of our rules and policies is not considered a valid excuse for violating them. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_blue_diamond:" src="/assets/85e5fb9f60873c46d98c8ab4efdf4066.svg" alt=":small_blue_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Failure to comply or respond to a request made by a staff member or moderator could result in punishment given at the discretion of staff member or moderator. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":tarantula:" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/707342234743472218.png?v=1" alt=":tarantula:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>Tarantula Bite Strike System</strong> Individuals will receive one tarantula bite for an infraction of the rules. Individuals will be banned for high-severity infractions of the rules. The use of slurs, hate speech, offensive content, or Real Money Trading (RMT) are some examples of infractions that can result in an immediate ban. Punishments are based on your cumulative total of bites. Note that there are occurrences where you can be banned before 5 bites. <strong>Mutes</strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Two tarantula bites = 1 hour mute <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Three tarantula bites = 4 hour mute <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Four tarantula bites = 12 hour mute <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Five tarantula bites = Ban <em>Credit to Animal Crossing: New Horizon's Discord for Bug-Infraction Rule System!</em> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":pencil:" src="/assets/e1ec53c5d89c0291001989a36716aa9a.svg" alt=":pencil:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong><u>REVIEW RULES</u></strong> <strong>The following are permitted reviews, regardless of star ranking:</strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Completed trade <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> The user was rude when interacting with them Auctions-Specific: <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Villager Auction was not completed after 24 hours* <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Non-Villager Auction was not completed after 48 hours* <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Auction canceled by seller/buyer* <strong>Leaving a review for these reasons is not permitted:</strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> As a requirement for trading/event hosting/giveaway. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Congratulating a user on milestone/achievement/giveaway without trade <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Trying to contact a user about a listing. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviews with abusive language/profanity <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Commenting on listings/pricing. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviews left in response to other reviews</blockquote>
                </div>
                <time datetime="2021-03-03T00:53:57.698Z" class="edited-3sfAzf" role="note" aria-label="Tuesday, March 2, 2021 4:53 PM">(edited)</time>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-1ov-mD"></div>
        <div class="buttonContainer-DHceWr">
            <div class="buttons-cl5qTG container-3npvBV" aria-label="Message Actions">
                <div class="wrapper-2aW0bm">
                    <div class="button-1ZiXG9" aria-label="More" aria-controls="popout_1628" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0">
                        <svg class="icon-3Gkjwa" aria-hidden="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7 12.001C7 10.8964 6.10457 10.001 5 10.001C3.89543 10.001 3 10.8964 3 12.001C3 13.1055 3.89543 14.001 5 14.001C6.10457 14.001 7 13.1055 7 12.001ZM14 12.001C14 10.8964 13.1046 10.001 12 10.001C10.8954 10.001 10 10.8964 10 12.001C10 13.1055 10.8954 14.001 12 14.001C13.1046 14.001 14 13.1055 14 12.001ZM19 10.001C20.1046 10.001 21 10.8964 21 12.001C21 13.1055 20.1046 14.001 19 14.001C17.8954 14.001 17 13.1055 17 12.001C17 10.8964 17.8954 10.001 19 10.001Z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-718562178684158015" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-718562178684158015">
        <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><span class="latin24CompactTimeStamp-2V7XIQ timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampVisibleOnHover-2bQeI4 alt-1uNpEt"><span aria-label="1:29 PM"><i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">[</i>1:29 PM<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">] </i></span></span>
            <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC">
                <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
                    <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
                    <blockquote><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Commenting on listings/pricing <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviews left in response to other reviews <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviewing on behalf of other users <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Canceled Trades (buyer or seller) <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Auction ended and never heard a response BEFORE 48 Hours (24 hours for Villagers) * Please note that multiple failed auctions is a reportable offense, and can result in strikes/bans. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":judge:" src="/assets/581744e66dae5ebd54b563d527478f93.svg" alt=":judge:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong><u>Auction Rules</u></strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> If the buyer (i.e. winner of the auction) or the seller does not follow through with the transaction within 48 hours, the buyer or seller has the right to report that user. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Depending on the circumstance, Nookazon has the right to bite and/or ban users for not following through with auctions. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Auctions cannot be cancelled once a bid has been made. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Bids made on the site must be honored. Cross-platform auctions between site and server are prohibited. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Attempts to haggle with the buyer after an auction has been won are not allowed. </blockquote>
                </div>
                <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
                    <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
                    <blockquote><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":warning:" src="/assets/289673858e06dfa2e0e3a7ee610c3a30.svg" alt=":warning:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong><u>DISCLAIMER</u></strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":warning:" src="/assets/289673858e06dfa2e0e3a7ee610c3a30.svg" alt=":warning:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> These rules are NOT exhaustive. Just because it is not listed, does NOT mean it is allowed. Check the pins by clicking the<span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":pushpin:" src="/assets/09204f6a96455580e749454b7449aa82.svg" alt=":pushpin:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> in each channel for important rules, guidelines, etc. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":revolving_hearts:" src="/assets/430e873bc74e81778ccf63f5d440f0ca.svg" alt=":revolving_hearts:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Friendly reminder that all mods are humans, not robots. They do their best to respond to all issues in a timely manner and to their best discretion. <em>If you would like to submit a mod appreciation letter, you can do so by typing ?send in any channel</em>! If you have a concern with moderation practices or a particular member of our moderation team, please submit a report via <a class="anchor-3Z-8Bb anchorUnderlineOnHover-2ESHQB" title="xxxxx" href="xxxxx" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank" role="button" tabindex="0">xxxxx</a>. These reports are handled by non-moderation team Nookazon staff to ensure fair and unbiased reviews. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":nookazon:" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/705612765561094174.png?v=1" alt=":nookazon:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>We hope you enjoy your time here with Nookazon!</strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":ballot_box_with_check:" src="/assets/86c16c39d96283551fd4ca7392e22681.svg" alt=":ballot_box_with_check:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> By clicking either check mark, you indicate that you have read and agree to abide by the above rules and policies, and you understand that these rules and policies are not exhaustive and are subject to change.</blockquote>
                </div>
                <time datetime="2021-03-03T00:54:27.794Z" class="edited-3sfAzf" role="note" aria-label="Tuesday, March 2, 2021 4:54 PM">(edited)</time>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-1ov-mD">
            <div class="reactions-12N0jA" role="group" aria-label="Reactions">
                <div>
                    <div class="reaction-1hd86g" style="opacity: 1;">
                        <div aria-controls="popout_1620" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label="✅, press to react" aria-pressed="false"><img src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt="✅" draggable="false" class="emoji">
                                <div class="reactionCount-2mvXRV" style="min-width: 45px;">15271</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="reaction-1hd86g" style="opacity: 1;">
                        <div aria-controls="popout_1621" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label="☑️, press to react" aria-pressed="false"><img src="/assets/86c16c39d96283551fd4ca7392e22681.svg" alt="☑️" draggable="false" class="emoji">
                                <div class="reactionCount-2mvXRV" style="min-width: 36px;">9731</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer-DHceWr">
            <div class="buttons-cl5qTG container-3npvBV" aria-label="Message Actions">
                <div class="wrapper-2aW0bm">
                    <div class="button-1ZiXG9" aria-label="More" aria-controls="popout_1627" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0">
                        <svg class="icon-3Gkjwa" aria-hidden="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7 12.001C7 10.8964 6.10457 10.001 5 10.001C3.89543 10.001 3 10.8964 3 12.001C3 13.1055 3.89543 14.001 5 14.001C6.10457 14.001 7 13.1055 7 12.001ZM14 12.001C14 10.8964 13.1046 10.001 12 10.001C10.8954 10.001 10 10.8964 10 12.001C10 13.1055 10.8954 14.001 12 14.001C13.1046 14.001 14 13.1055 14 12.001ZM19 10.001C20.1046 10.001 21 10.8964 21 12.001C21 13.1055 20.1046 14.001 19 14.001C17.8954 14.001 17 13.1055 17 12.001C17 10.8964 17.8954 10.001 19 10.001Z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider-3_HH5L hasContent-1_DUdQ divider-JfaTT5 hasContent-1cNJDh"><span class="content-1o0f9g">June 8, 2020</span></div>
    <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y groupStart-23k01U wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-719650608935731211" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-719650608935731211">
        <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/717491799014506551/7915934d00f156ee499963d2c14ecdf8.png?size=256" aria-hidden="true" class="avatar-1BDn8e clickable-1bVtEA" alt=" ">
            <h2 class="header-23xsNx"><span class="headerText-3Uvj1Y"><span class="username-1A8OIy clickable-1bVtEA" aria-controls="popout_1623" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0">nookazon</span></span><span class="timestamp-3ZCmNB"><span aria-label="06/08/2020">06/08/2020</span></span></h2>
            <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC"><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":arrow_up:" src="/assets/b51c7cfe515fd884537ca5c2ac8ce7a2.svg" alt=":arrow_up:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> If you <strong>do not</strong> see the checkmarks under the above message, make sure you have Reaction Emojis enabled in your Discord settings.
                <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
                    <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
                    <blockquote>Go to User Settings <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":gear:" src="/assets/a6d05968d7706183143518d96c9f066e.svg" alt=":gear:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> → Text &amp; Images → Emoji <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":warning:" src="/assets/289673858e06dfa2e0e3a7ee610c3a30.svg" alt=":warning:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> If you are having trouble receiving full access, make sure that you have reacted to get the role. After, <em>please wait up to 10 minutes</em> due to traffic as the bot can get overloaded. If this doesn't work, <em>restart Discord</em> (control/command R), then attempt to click on it again. If you are still having troubles, please ask in <span class="wrapper-3WhCwL mention interactive" tabindex="0" role="button">#❔-help</span> after you have attempted the troubleshooting methods above.</blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-1ov-mD"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollerSpacer-avRLaA"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the text from the last "message-XXXXX" entry. So I've tried this:

```
document.querySelector(“div.scrollerInner-XXXXX:last-child”).innerContent
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Am I getting this code right? I'm also wondering if that nested "scrollerSpacer"  at the very end is throwing things off. I'm not 100% convinced that's the case, because when I delete it using inspect-elements the script still fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you -S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like the last element is followed by

```
<div class="scrollerSpacer-XXXXXX"><div>
```

I'd select *that* element, then navigate to its previous sibling:

```js
const spacer = document.querySelector('[class^="scrollerSpacer"]');
const finalMessageElement = spacer.previousElementSibling
console.log(finalMessageElement);
console.log(finalMessageElement.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="scrollerInner-2YIMLh" aria-label="Messages in -rules-you-must-read" role="log" aria-orientation="vertical" data-list-id="chat-messages" tabindex="0" aria-live="off"><span class="navigationDescription-3hiGKr" id="messagesNavigationDescription" aria-hidden="true">Use the up and down arrow keys to navigate between messages quickly. New messages will be added to the bottom of the list as they come in.</span>
  <div class="container-3RCQyg" id="chat-messages-701975798466216026">
    <div class="container-3zqIcM">
      <div class="inner-3GZ54g">
        <div>
          <div class="colorHeaderPrimary-26Jzh- size32-o_H79z titleName-3-Lp3Z">
            <p>Welcome to</p>
            <p>Nookazon</p>
          </div>
          <div class="colorHeaderSecondary-3Sp3Ft size14-e6ZScH subtitle-2UIIw0 noChildren-1pQQQE">This is the beginning of this server. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-718562073835208774" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-718562073835208774">
    <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><span class="latin24CompactTimeStamp-2V7XIQ timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampVisibleOnHover-2bQeI4 alt-1uNpEt"><span aria-label="1:29 PM"><i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">[</i>1:29 PM<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">] </i></span></span>
      <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC"><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":eight:" src="/assets/71de2e3efd19455f1c63b9bd00329ec5.svg" alt=":eight:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>Spam</strong>
        <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
          <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
          <blockquote>Use of our website or Discord server in any way deemed to be spam will result in the termination of your account. This includes but is not limited to excessively using all capitalizations or spaces, and posting repeatedly, low effort, and/or
            inappropriate messages that contribute little to no meaning in the discussion regardless of timeframe, chain mail, or messages that are overall irrelevant. Excessively large messages, 15 lines or greater, are also considered spam, and will
            be dealt with accordingly. Please refrain from spamming pings, images, messages, or listings. Attempting to contact other users in any way for purposes deemed to be spam will not be tolerated. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button"
              tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":speech_balloon:" src="/assets/df8b5c1e4abb97e748071aeb28f1ba38.svg" alt=":speech_balloon:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>Use Chat and Trade Channels Appropriately</strong> Please use the appropriate
            trade channels for your discussions. All channel descriptions are located at the top of each channel. If you are unsure about where to post, please ask in <span class="wrapper-3WhCwL mention interactive" tabindex="0" role="button">#❔-help</span>.
            Punishments for trolling/baiting are more severe in the trading channels. You may receive a mute for any off-topic content in these channels. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":vibration_mode:" src="/assets/c039d0f4fb5cee040c7aa7c80da104d8.svg" alt=":vibration_mode:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            <strong>No Mass Pings</strong> Mass pinging individuals will result in an <em>auto-ban</em>. You may ping up to <strong><u>three</u></strong> mods or @ emergency if attention is needed in a channel. Abuse may result in a bite/ban. </blockquote>
        </div><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":clipboard:" src="/assets/1bfac5a4300cf5668073bd17d178e89e.svg" alt=":clipboard:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong>Keep your trading lists concise</strong>.
        <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
          <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
          <blockquote>If you have more than 10 items to trade per item category, please add them to your catalog on the site and share your Nookazon profile link in the appropriate trade channel. </blockquote>
        </div><em> </em>
        <time datetime="2021-01-04T04:35:25.481Z" class="edited-3sfAzf" role="note" aria-label="Sunday, January 3, 2021 8:35 PM">(edited)</time>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1ov-mD"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-718562140486631455" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-718562140486631455">
    <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><span class="latin24CompactTimeStamp-2V7XIQ timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampVisibleOnHover-2bQeI4 alt-1uNpEt"><span aria-label="1:29 PM"><i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">[</i>1:29 PM<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">] </i></span></span>
      <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC"><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":keycap_ten:" src="/assets/5e1630b749695f21d61dcf55fc09c2b6.svg" alt=":keycap_ten:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button"
          tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":bangbang:" src="/assets/9a13b8821ec2c880981df4bf3ce07177.svg" alt=":bangbang:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span><strong><u>Tarantula Bites</u></strong><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":bangbang:" src="/assets/9a13b8821ec2c880981df4bf3ce07177.svg" alt=":bangbang:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>
        <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
          <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
          <blockquote> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_blue_diamond:" src="/assets/85e5fb9f60873c46d98c8ab4efdf4066.svg" alt=":small_blue_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Ignorance of our rules
            and policies is not considered a valid excuse for violating them. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_blue_diamond:" src="/assets/85e5fb9f60873c46d98c8ab4efdf4066.svg" alt=":small_blue_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Failure to comply or respond to a request made by a staff member or moderator could result in punishment given at the discretion of staff member or moderator. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":tarantula:" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/707342234743472218.png?v=1" alt=":tarantula:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            <strong>Tarantula Bite Strike System</strong> Individuals will receive one tarantula bite for an infraction of the rules. Individuals will be banned for high-severity infractions of the rules. The use of slurs, hate speech, offensive content,
            or Real Money Trading (RMT) are some examples of infractions that can result in an immediate ban. Punishments are based on your cumulative total of bites. Note that there are occurrences where you can be banned before 5 bites. <strong>Mutes</strong>            <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Two tarantula bites
            = 1 hour mute <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Three
            tarantula bites = 4 hour mute <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Four tarantula bites = 12 hour mute <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Five tarantula bites = Ban <em>Credit to Animal Crossing: New Horizon's Discord for Bug-Infraction Rule System!</em> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":pencil:" src="/assets/e1ec53c5d89c0291001989a36716aa9a.svg" alt=":pencil:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            <strong><u>REVIEW RULES</u></strong> <strong>The following are permitted reviews, regardless of star ranking:</strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Completed trade <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> The user
            was rude when interacting with them Auctions-Specific: <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Villager Auction was not completed after 24 hours* <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Non-Villager Auction was not completed after 48 hours* <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Auction canceled by seller/buyer* <strong>Leaving a review for these reasons is not permitted:</strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            As a requirement for trading/event hosting/giveaway. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Congratulating a user on milestone/achievement/giveaway without trade <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Trying to contact a user about a listing. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviews with
            abusive language/profanity <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Commenting on listings/pricing.
            <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviews left in response to other reviews</blockquote>
        </div>
        <time datetime="2021-03-03T00:53:57.698Z" class="edited-3sfAzf" role="note" aria-label="Tuesday, March 2, 2021 4:53 PM">(edited)</time>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1ov-mD"></div>
    <div class="buttonContainer-DHceWr">
      <div class="buttons-cl5qTG container-3npvBV" aria-label="Message Actions">
        <div class="wrapper-2aW0bm">
          <div class="button-1ZiXG9" aria-label="More" aria-controls="popout_1628" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0">
            <svg class="icon-3Gkjwa" aria-hidden="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7 12.001C7 10.8964 6.10457 10.001 5 10.001C3.89543 10.001 3 10.8964 3 12.001C3 13.1055 3.89543 14.001 5 14.001C6.10457 14.001 7 13.1055 7 12.001ZM14 12.001C14 10.8964 13.1046 10.001 12 10.001C10.8954 10.001 10 10.8964 10 12.001C10 13.1055 10.8954 14.001 12 14.001C13.1046 14.001 14 13.1055 14 12.001ZM19 10.001C20.1046 10.001 21 10.8964 21 12.001C21 13.1055 20.1046 14.001 19 14.001C17.8954 14.001 17 13.1055 17 12.001C17 10.8964 17.8954 10.001 19 10.001Z"></path>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-718562178684158015" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-718562178684158015">
    <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><span class="latin24CompactTimeStamp-2V7XIQ timestamp-3ZCmNB timestampVisibleOnHover-2bQeI4 alt-1uNpEt"><span aria-label="1:29 PM"><i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">[</i>1:29 PM<i class="separator-2nZzUB" aria-hidden="true">] </i></span></span>
      <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC">
        <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
          <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
          <blockquote><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Commenting on listings/pricing <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE"
              role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviews left in response to other reviews <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button"
              tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Reviewing on behalf of other users <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Canceled Trades (buyer or seller) <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":x:" src="/assets/8becd37ab9d13cdfe37c08c496a9def3.svg" alt=":x:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> Auction ended and never
            heard a response BEFORE 48 Hours (24 hours for Villagers) * Please note that multiple failed auctions is a reportable offense, and can result in strikes/bans. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":judge:" src="/assets/581744e66dae5ebd54b563d527478f93.svg" alt=":judge:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            <strong><u>Auction Rules</u></strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            If the buyer (i.e. winner of the auction) or the seller does not follow through with the transaction within 48 hours, the buyer or seller has the right to report that user. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Depending on the circumstance, Nookazon has the right to bite and/or ban users for not following through with auctions. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Auctions cannot be cancelled once a bid has been made. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Bids made on the site must be honored. Cross-platform auctions between site and server are prohibited. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":small_orange_diamond:" src="/assets/893165570015b53aad1a6999d13ea7d8.svg" alt=":small_orange_diamond:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Attempts to haggle with the buyer after an auction has been won are not allowed. </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
          <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
          <blockquote><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":warning:" src="/assets/289673858e06dfa2e0e3a7ee610c3a30.svg" alt=":warning:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> <strong><u>DISCLAIMER</u></strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE"
              role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":warning:" src="/assets/289673858e06dfa2e0e3a7ee610c3a30.svg" alt=":warning:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> These rules are NOT exhaustive. Just because it is not listed, does NOT mean
            it is allowed. Check the pins by clicking the<span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":pushpin:" src="/assets/09204f6a96455580e749454b7449aa82.svg" alt=":pushpin:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            in each channel for important rules, guidelines, etc. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":revolving_hearts:" src="/assets/430e873bc74e81778ccf63f5d440f0ca.svg" alt=":revolving_hearts:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            Friendly reminder that all mods are humans, not robots. They do their best to respond to all issues in a timely manner and to their best discretion. <em>If you would like to submit a mod appreciation letter, you can do so by typing ?send in any channel</em>!
            If you have a concern with moderation practices or a particular member of our moderation team, please submit a report via <a class="anchor-3Z-8Bb anchorUnderlineOnHover-2ESHQB" title="xxxxx" href="xxxxx" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank"
              role="button" tabindex="0">xxxxx</a>. These reports are handled by non-moderation team Nookazon staff to ensure fair and unbiased reviews. <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":nookazon:" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/705612765561094174.png?v=1" alt=":nookazon:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>            <strong>We hope you enjoy your time here with Nookazon!</strong> <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":white_check_mark:" src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt=":white_check_mark:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span>
            <span
              class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":ballot_box_with_check:" src="/assets/86c16c39d96283551fd4ca7392e22681.svg" alt=":ballot_box_with_check:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> By clicking either check mark, you indicate that you have read and agree to
              abide by the above rules and policies, and you understand that these rules and policies are not exhaustive and are subject to change.</blockquote>
        </div>
        <time datetime="2021-03-03T00:54:27.794Z" class="edited-3sfAzf" role="note" aria-label="Tuesday, March 2, 2021 4:54 PM">(edited)</time>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1ov-mD">
      <div class="reactions-12N0jA" role="group" aria-label="Reactions">
        <div>
          <div class="reaction-1hd86g" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div aria-controls="popout_1620" aria-expanded="false">
              <div class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label="✅, press to react" aria-pressed="false"><img src="/assets/212e30e47232be03033a87dc58edaa95.svg" alt="✅" draggable="false" class="emoji">
                <div class="reactionCount-2mvXRV" style="min-width: 45px;">15271</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="reaction-1hd86g" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div aria-controls="popout_1621" aria-expanded="false">
              <div class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label="☑️, press to react" aria-pressed="false"><img src="/assets/86c16c39d96283551fd4ca7392e22681.svg" alt="☑️" draggable="false" class="emoji">
                <div class="reactionCount-2mvXRV" style="min-width: 36px;">9731</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonContainer-DHceWr">
      <div class="buttons-cl5qTG container-3npvBV" aria-label="Message Actions">
        <div class="wrapper-2aW0bm">
          <div class="button-1ZiXG9" aria-label="More" aria-controls="popout_1627" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0">
            <svg class="icon-3Gkjwa" aria-hidden="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7 12.001C7 10.8964 6.10457 10.001 5 10.001C3.89543 10.001 3 10.8964 3 12.001C3 13.1055 3.89543 14.001 5 14.001C6.10457 14.001 7 13.1055 7 12.001ZM14 12.001C14 10.8964 13.1046 10.001 12 10.001C10.8954 10.001 10 10.8964 10 12.001C10 13.1055 10.8954 14.001 12 14.001C13.1046 14.001 14 13.1055 14 12.001ZM19 10.001C20.1046 10.001 21 10.8964 21 12.001C21 13.1055 20.1046 14.001 19 14.001C17.8954 14.001 17 13.1055 17 12.001C17 10.8964 17.8954 10.001 19 10.001Z"></path>
                        </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divider-3_HH5L hasContent-1_DUdQ divider-JfaTT5 hasContent-1cNJDh"><span class="content-1o0f9g">June 8, 2020</span></div>
  <div class="message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y groupStart-23k01U wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-719650608935731211" tabindex="-1" id="chat-messages-719650608935731211">
    <div class="contents-2mQqc9" role="document"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/717491799014506551/7915934d00f156ee499963d2c14ecdf8.png?size=256" aria-hidden="true" class="avatar-1BDn8e clickable-1bVtEA" alt=" ">
      <h2 class="header-23xsNx"><span class="headerText-3Uvj1Y"><span class="username-1A8OIy clickable-1bVtEA" aria-controls="popout_1623" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0">nookazon</span></span><span class="timestamp-3ZCmNB"><span aria-label="06/08/2020">06/08/2020</span></span>
      </h2>
      <div class="markup-2BOw-j messageContent-2qWWxC"><span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":arrow_up:" src="/assets/b51c7cfe515fd884537ca5c2ac8ce7a2.svg" alt=":arrow_up:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> If you <strong>do not</strong> see the checkmarks
        under the above message, make sure you have Reaction Emojis enabled in your Discord settings.
        <div class="blockquoteContainer-U5TVEi">
          <div class="blockquoteDivider-2hH8H6"></div>
          <blockquote>Go to User Settings <span class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":gear:" src="/assets/a6d05968d7706183143518d96c9f066e.svg" alt=":gear:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> → Text &amp; Images → Emoji
            <span
              class="emojiContainer-3X8SvE" role="button" tabindex="0"><img aria-label=":warning:" src="/assets/289673858e06dfa2e0e3a7ee610c3a30.svg" alt=":warning:" draggable="false" class="emoji"></span> If you are having trouble receiving full access, make sure that you have reacted to get the role. After,
              <em>please wait up to 10 minutes</em> due to traffic as the bot can get overloaded. If this doesn't work, <em>restart Discord</em> (control/command R), then attempt to click on it again. If you are still having troubles, please ask in
              <span
                class="wrapper-3WhCwL mention interactive" tabindex="0" role="button">#❔-help</span> after you have attempted the troubleshooting methods above.</blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1ov-mD"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollerSpacer-avRLaA"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a pretty slick idea. For whatever reason it's still not returning any data for me though.

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" to see the code in the answer working. If it isn't working in your real application, then the HTML structure is not the same as in your question. Please edit your question to include the *actual* HTML structure verbatim.

Comment: You're right - I got the structure a little wrong. I've added the extra detail in my original post. I could copy the whole html block verbatim, but it would be very, very long. I've tried to abbreviate. Let me know if you'd like the whole thing though. In any case, I'm still having trouble getting the script to grab the innerText. Thank you very much for taking a look.

Comment: I edited the snippet to change to the new HTML in the question and the code provided in the answer still works, as you can see by pressing Run Code Snippet

Comment: Thanks. I definitely see it's working in the snippet. Weird though, when I run it on the real deal in fiddle it seems to want to grab the contents of <span class="navigationDescription-XXXXX">. When I remove that element it functions well. Curious.

Comment: Perhaps the elements don't get populated on pageload? Try running your scraper only after a few seconds, instead of immediately

Comment: Good call. I'm trying it in a sandbox in jsfiddle, just copy/pasting the html into there, so load time shouldn't be a factor. Weirdly, on the sample html here, it works on SO, but on jsfiddle it returns June 8, 2020 from the divider div. Man I'm confused haha.

Comment: The problem you describe is not reproducible given the current code. Please edit the actual code into the question if you want a solution

Comment: It currently gives the message of `If you <strong>do not</strong> see the checkmarks under the above message, make sure you have Reaction Emojis enabled in your Discord settings.` That looks to be the last message in the list..? Or were you hoping for something else?

Comment: The result you got is correct, but when I run it with the snippet tool above, I get a much longer result, encompassing multiple user posts.

Comment: I don't see it. When I run the snippet, I only see that one message by nookazon06. The message spans multiple lines, but it's still only one user's message.

Comment: Actually you're right, apologies. It works in the snippet tool. Where I'm getting issues is on jsfiddle and my production platform. There is seems to return the whole spiel. But it does seem to work here so there must be something going on on my side. I won't take up any more of your time. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `:last-child` pseudoselector applies to the element it is attached to. In this case, you're selecting the last `.scrollerInner-XXXXX` div that is a child of it's parent element, not the last `.message-XXXXX`.

However, since a `.message-XXXXX` element is not the last child of the `.scrollerInner-XXXXX` element, you can't use `:last-child`. You have to use `:last-of-type` instead.

In conclusion, you want to query for `.scrollerInner-XXXXX .message-XXXXX:last-of-type`:

```js
document.querySelector('.scrollerInner-XXXXX .message-XXXXX:last-of-type');
```

This assumes `.message-XXXXX` is the same for every message.

---

Otherwise, you'll want to get the children of `.scrollerInner-XXXXX` and filter them by class names, then get the last one.

```js
const scrollerInnerChildren = Array.from(document.querySelector('.scrollerInner-XXXXX').children);

const hasMessagesFilter = child => Array.from(child.classList).some(cl => cl.startsWith('message-'));

const childrenWithMessages = scrollerInnerChildren.filter(hasMessagesFilter);

const { length } = childrenWithMessages;

const lastMessageElement = childrenWithMessages[length - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes alot of sense. The "message" field is constant across all entries, yes. However, it has a weird structure that I failed to put in my original post. I've updated the post with the extra detail. Here's what the message identifier looks like:

'"message-2qnXI6 cozyMessage-3V1Y8y wrapper-2a6GCs cozy-3raOZG zalgo-jN1Ica"

Not sure what to do with those spaces in there. I tried your script with the "last of type" selector, and unfortunately it didn't work on Discord.

Comment: Like @CertainPerformance's solution, this also seems to be grabbing the text from <span class="navigationDescription-XXXXX">. There must be some differences in the real code that I'm not accurately transcribing. Should I post the real thing? It's quite large. But when I try this on my structure example it works, but not on the real code.